# Travis is not uploading cache directory? Why?

Tags: travis-ci

On this build, I have a cache directory in the settings, 
where I install all dependencies, strangely travis does not execute `before_cache` and does not upload the cache?

My repository uses the settings as explained for caching:
[image]

https://travis-ci.org/gabyx/ApproxMVBB/jobs/256581132

Its strange that travis reports the following in the log

```
Setting up build cache
$ export CASHER_DIR=$HOME/.casher
0.14s$ Installing caching utilities
0.00s
0.61sattempting to download cache archive
fetching master/cache-linux-precise-49ed8168a954ef68babd02034884f858ddc4fe3ca0368ba1270828dc239856eb--compiler-gpp.tgz
fetching master/cache--compiler-gpp.tgz
could not download cache
0.00s
0.45sadding /home/travis/ApproxMVBBCache to cache
creating directory /home/travis/ApproxMVBBCache
```

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Providing `.travis.yml` would be helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/gabyx/ApproxMVBB/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: You've put `before_cache` after `script`. I don't know if order matters, but try following the one said in docs.

Comment: Also, add the Travis code in question for easy reference.

Comment: Also, add  Travis code in question for easy reference.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: I was sourcing the bash scripts, and have done an `exit 0` in build.sh which exits the build.